# Same custom set property for some class field

Tags: c#, winforms

I want every time that TextBox filed is set the back color change according to the sign.

```
    public TextBox Current_value_text1
    {
        get { return Current_value_text; }
        set { 
                Current_value_text = value;
                if (Current_value_text.Text[0] == '+')
                    Current_value_text.BackColor = Color.Green;
                else
                    Current_value_text.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
    }
```

but I want to do this for all my textbox fields - any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for `TextChanged` event?

Comment: lets forget about TextBox for a sec, I want to know if there is an option to customize set for some fields in my class, for example:

            `public int num1
        {
            get { return num1; }
            set
            {

                if (value == 1)
                    num1 = value + 1;
                else
                    num1 = value - 1;
            }
        }`
but I want to do the same action on num2 and num3 etc,
can I do it?

Comment: extract a method? `private void MyNumPerform(ref int num, int value) {if (value == 1) num = value + 1; else num = value - 1;}` then use it: `public int num1 {get => m_Num1; set => MyNumPerform(ref m_Num1, value);}`

Comment: yes it could work, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for `TextChanged` event: whenever `TextBox`(es) change its `Text`, analyze it and update `BackColor` when necessary.

If it's your case, can select all the `Textbox`es (say, with a mouse), open "Properties" window and implement event hander for the `TextChanged`:

```
 private void myTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   TextBox box = sender as TextBox;

   if (null == box)
     return;

   box.BackColor = box.Text.Trim().StartsWith("-")
     ? Color.Red
     : Color.Green; 
 }
```

**EDIT:** The question in the *comment* is a quite *different case*; here we don't have events, but we can try *extracting a method* (`NumSet`):

```
 private int m_Num1;
 private int m_Num2;

 private void NumSet(ref int num, int value) {
   if (value == 1)
     num = value + 1;
   else
     num = value - 1; 
 } 

 public int Num1 {
   get => m_Num1;
   set => NumSet(ref m_Num1, value);  
 }

 public int Num2 {
   get => m_Num2;
   set => NumSet(ref m_Num2, value);  
 }
```

Comment: lets forget about TextBox for a sec, I want to know if there is an option to customize set for some fields in my class, for example:

            public int num1
        {
            get { return num1; }
            set
            {

                if (value == 1)
                    num1 = value + 1;
                else
                    num1 = value - 1;
            }
        }
but I want to do the same action on num2 and num3 etc,
can I do it?